# Как отслеживать кол-во серверов на которых установлен бот? (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, бот, discord

Я смотрел на некоторых ботов, которые показывают в статусе кол-во отслеживаемых серверов или же пользователей. Знаю только два способа - **Статус**, **Команда**.

Т.к. это реально, значит возможно, но как...? Если не сложно, разберите все возможные варианты подробнее, буду рад узнать что-то новое :D

**Discord.js@12.2.0**

Answer (score 2):

12 версия

```js
client.guilds.cache.size
```

11 версия

```js
client.guilds.size
```